# 'max-height' and horizontal scrollbars causing IE8 to go into Compatibility Mode (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I'm using ASP.NET to have a panel that can expand downwards to a certain point, at which point the user can scroll within the panel, both vertically and horizontally (horizontally because one GridView has a lot of columns which would be impossible to display without horizontal scrollbars in the panel/div)

Problem is, if I set the panel (asp:Panel control) that holds the GridView to have Scrollbars="Both", and have a max-height set on the panel, IE8 refreshes into compatibility mode. If I remove the max height, or have only vertical scrollbars, it works fine. Any workarounds for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an X-UA-compatible meta-tag to tell IE8 to render your page in standards mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that seems to stop my whole page rendering though - I just get a white page

Comment: Hmm, weird. Did you add the meta element to the head element? Do you have any _major_ errors in your HTML when validating with W3C validator?

Comment: No major errors at all, and yup it was in the header. From Googling seems like it's a bug in IE8 which causes entire pages to not display!